# Set zeros to those columns where first row contains ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset:

```
id 1 2 3 
1  1 0 1
2  1 1 1
3  0 1 1
```

What is the fastest way to set zeroes to those columns where first row contains ones, so that output looks like that:

```
id 1 2 3 
1  0 0 0
2  0 1 0
3  0 1 0
```

Comment: IMO, bad dupe.  That question is asking based on another *column*, not *row*, as well as not being a solution that can applied to multiple columns at once.  I am not going to re-open since I have an answer here, but if this is a dupe I think a better target is required.

Comment: @user3483203 I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arithmetic here.

---

```
df.iloc[0].ne(1) * df
```

```
   1  2  3
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  1  0
```

---

***Explanation***

```
>>> df.iloc[0].ne(1)
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Index alignment takes care of the rest, and multiples all columns where the condition is not met by `0`.  This is a bit more memory intensive since it returns a copy of the DataFrame, but a neat trick nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns[df.iloc[0].to_numpy(bool)]] = 0
df
```

Output:

```
    1  2  3
id         
1   0  0  0
2   0  1  0
3   0  1  0
```

Use `iloc` to select the first row, then convert those values to a numpy array using `to_numpy` with dtype of boolean.

Next, use boolean indexing on the dataframe column headers to determine which columns to set all values to zero using `loc`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `reindex`

```
df.loc[:,df.iloc[0]!=1].reindex(columns=df.columns,fill_value=0)
Out[814]: 
    1  2  3
id         
1   0  0  0
2   0  1  0
3   0  1  0
```